# How to handle ExpressJS optional route parameters with TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, routes

I have the following code:

#### `index.ts`

```js
import express from "express";
import { Uuid } from "./Uuid";
import { UuidGen } from "./Uuid_gen";

const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 3000;

app.get("/Uuidgen/1/:operatingAgency/:locId?", (request, result) =>
    result.send(UuidGen.generateType1Uuid(request.params.operatingAgency, request.params.locId).toString())
);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`UUID Generator listening on port ${port}`));
```

Now, when the file is saved with a `.ts` extension, the TypeScript compiler complains:

[image]

Now, when the 'Quick Fix' is applied, this is the resulting code:

```
app.get("/Uuidgen/1/:operatingAgency/:locId?", (request, result) =>
    result.send(UuidGen.generateType1Uuid(request.params.operatingAgency, request.params["locId?"]).toString())
```

This compiles fine, but the `locId` parameter is never passed to the callback function and is empty. What can I do? A temporary solution is to change the extension to `.js` and ensure `"checkJs": false` in `tsconfig.json`, but ideally I'd like my entire project in TypeScript.

I have `@types/express` listed under `devDependencies` in `package.json`.

Comment: There's an [open PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/53513) that addresses this problem. Until it gets merged, you may want to use a query string instead.

Comment: Speak of the devil, it was reviewed not two days ago. Thanks; I tried using `<string>req.query.locId` instead, but this does not work either. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The express library has the `Request` interface with generic type for `Params`, `Query`, `Body`. This would work for this case. For example:

```
import express, { Request } from 'express';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 3000;

interface RequestParams {
    locId?: number;
    operatingAgency: string;
}

app.get('/Uuidgen/1/:operatingAgency/:locId?', (request: Request<RequestParams>, result) =>
  result.send(UuidGen.generateType1Uuid(request.params.operatingAgency, request.params.locId).toString()),
);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`UUID Generator listening on port ${port}`));
```